# using Spring Boot 3 and spring graphql, the endpoint /graphql isn't being exposed on my graphql tests (it's working fine when I run the system)

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I'm running a system using Java 17 + Spring Boot 3.0.5 and Spring GraphQL.
When I run the system, all works fine. I'm able to execute my query and mutations using the graphiql or any other UI, like Postman.

However, when I run my tests, the endpoint /graphql isn't exposed:

```
2023-04-14 | 12:15:37.783 | main                 | ERROR | ExchangeResult.assertWithDiagnostics - Request details for assertion failure:

> POST http://localhost:57947/graphql
> accept-encoding: [gzip]
> user-agent: [ReactorNetty/1.1.5]
> host: [localhost:57947]
> WebTestClient-Request-Id: [1]
> Content-Type: [application/json]
> Accept: [application/json]
> Content-Length: [180]

{"query":"myGraphQLQuery(\n    source:{countryCode:\"GB\", locale:\"en-US\"},\n    amount:{value:\"150.00\", currency:\"GBP\"}\n) {\n    provider\n    method\n    specifics\n}"}

< 404 NOT_FOUND Not Found < Date: [Fri, 14 Apr 2023 11:15:37 GMT] < Content-Type: [application/json] < Content-Length: [116]

{"timestamp":1681470937706,"path":"/graphql","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":null,"requestId":"2c691d2e"}


java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200 OK> but was:<404 NOT_FOUND>
```

I'm executing a very simple test just to understand why the /graphql endpoint isn't being exposed.
If I compare with another system that's working fine, I could check that this line isn't being shown on my log when I run my test:

```
2023-04-14 | 10:59:57.007 | main                 |  INFO | GraphQlWebFluxAutoConfiguration.? - GraphQL endpoint HTTP POST /graphql
```

my sample test:

```
package com.mycompany.test;

import com.mycompany.MyApplication;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.graphql.tester.AutoConfigureGraphQlTester;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.graphql.test.tester.GraphQlTester;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = MyApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureGraphQlTester
public class MyGraphqlTest {

    @Autowired
    protected GraphQlTester graphQlTester;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        GraphQlTester.Request<?> myGraphQLQuery = graphQlTester.documentName("myGraphQLQueryFile");
        GraphQlTester.Response response = myGraphQLQuery.execute();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

**Does anyone have any idea about this problem?**

Thanks

Sergio.

Comment: Can you try with `@GraphQlTest` instead of `@AutoConfigureGraphQlTester`

Springboot has a variety of Test annotations that autoconfigure things, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/test-auto-configuration.html

Comment: I am also running into the same issue. Did you find any solution for it? I am using spring boot 3.0.6